# How to run selenium webdriver with Python in CentOS 6.10 with Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, centos, geckodriver

I'm trying to run a Python script in a CentOS server. However, I've been unable to install Google Chrome (I've read it is no longer supported by CentOS) so I decided to try with Firefox. However, I get the following error when trying to run it with Firefox.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/uscomplianceserv/public_html/scrapdata/FMCSAScraper.py", line 73, in <module>
init_selenium()
File "/home/uscomplianceserv/public_html/scrapdata/FMCSAScraper.py", line 40, in init_selenium
webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options = options, executable_path='/home/uscomplianceserv/public_html/scrapdata/geckodriver')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 133, in __init__
if options.binary is not None:
AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'binary'
```

This is what I'm using:

- Centos 6.10
- Python 2.7
- Selenium 3.14.0
- Firefox 45
- Geckodriver v0.21.0

This is the selenium webdriver initialization function:

```
def init_selenium():
    global driver, page
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("-headless")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options = options, executable_path='/home/uscomplianceserv/public_html/scrapdata/geckodriver')
    driver.get(url)
```

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Comment: Done @DebanjanB

Comment: As per the error I still don't see `'Options' object` referring the `'binary'`. Am I missing something?